# How to disable Infinite Scroll button when there are not enough posts to enable it?

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll

We're using the Infinite Scroll plugin to load in paginated Wordpress pages. This is working great, however, when there are not enough posts to use Infinite Scroll, we are being left with the 'Load more' button, which obviously isn't required and has no functionality.

How can we hide the load more button when not required? Could we use is_paged() as a conditional, or is there something I'm missing in the Infinite Scroll documentation?

Thanks

**JQUERY**

```
// Init infinite scroll
$grid.infiniteScroll({
    path: '.pagination .next a',
    append: '.articles .article',
    outlayer: iso,
    loadOnScroll: false,
    scrollThreshold: false,
    button: '.load-more-button',
    hideNav: '.pagination',
    status: '.load-status',
    history: false,
    debug: true
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid articles">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="article">
        Article content here!
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>

<div class="load-more">
    <button class="load-more-button">Load More</button>
</div>

<nav class="grid pagination">
    <div class="prev"><?php echo get_previous_posts_link('Previous'); ?></div>
    <div class="next"><?php echo get_next_posts_link('Next'); ?></div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, that this may not seem as a professional answer, but it should work:

```
<div class="grid articles">
<?php
  $post_counter = 0;
?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
  $post_counter++;
?>
    <div class="article">
        Article content here!
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<?php
  if ( $post_counter > 5 ) {
?>
<div class="load-more">
    <button class="load-more-button">Load More</button>
</div>
<?php
  }
?>
<nav class="grid pagination">
    <div class="prev"><?php echo get_previous_posts_link('Previous'); ?></div>
    <div class="next"><?php echo get_next_posts_link('Next'); ?></div>
</nav>
```

So this is an easy, one-time-solution to the problem. One serious drawback, though: you have to hardcode the number in the PHP template.

Comment: Thank you @muka.gergely! Works perfectly. I have implemented and it's exactly what I was after. No need to hard code the number, I set this up as a variable, so it takes the number from the variable number of posts_per_page. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm happy this helped you! :)